# Extracting weeks if only year and month are given

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has  3 variables - Year, Month(in intergers) and NPS(value). I have to treat the data on a weekly basis. How can I extract week numbers from the following data? Also, NPS has to be changed accordingly.

```
Year        Month           NPS
2015         10             51
2015         11             50.5
2015         12             50
```

Comment: There are 4 to 5 weeks in a month. Do you know which day of the month the NPS value is recorded/reported for each row?

Comment: It is not given.

Comment: Since you only supply the month, do you want to get a range of weeks for each entry ? 2015-10 would be 40-43, 2015-11 would be 44-47, and so on ?

Comment: yeah, I would want it that way.

Answer (score 1):

As per mentioned in the comments, should you want a date range, you could do:

```
library(lubridate)

Start <- as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(paste0(df$Year, df$Month), "%Y%m"))
End   <- Start %m+% months(1) - 1

df$Weeks <- paste(week(Start), week(End) - 1, sep = "-")
```

Which gives:

```
#  Year Month  NPS Weeks
#1 2015    10 51.0 40-43
#2 2015    11 50.5 44-47
#3 2015    12 50.0 48-52
```